# How can I find a meteor mongodb collection from the shell?

Tags: mongodb, shell, meteor

When I go into "meteor mongo" OR "mongo localhost:3001", a shell opens up. If I 'show dbs', it displays:

```
customers  0.000GB
local      0.008GB
meteor     0.002GB
```

I created a collection during tinkering from within the shell and that currently is visible. What isn't visible, however, are the several collections that exist in my app! For example, in my meteor app, from localhost, I get a return of documents when I type 'Jobs.find().fetch()' and 'Tasks.find().fetch()'. If I update these documents, it persists after the app has been restarted.

These collections DO exist, but I don't know how to access them via shell.

Comment: If you are looking for tools to browse and modify collections you can go for `RoboMongo`

Comment: I should be able to do this in the shell itself, right?

Comment: All you meteor collections should be in the `meteor` db.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access your collections like that:

```
> use meteor;
> db.myCollection.find();
```

Answer (score 0):

try using robomongo. remember first to have meteor running

[image]